# Turn jQuery into vanilla JS - Insert p element after h1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas on how I would convert this jQuery to vanilla JS:

```
$('.section > h1').after('<p>This paragraph was inserted with jQuery</p>');
```

I am new to jQuery and even newer to vanilla JS.

This is as far as I got:

```
var newP = document.createElement('p');

var pTxt = document.createTextNode('This paragraph was inserted with JavaScript');

var header = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
```

Not sure where to go from here?

Comment: This would make a good blog post about why it's a big timesaver to use jQuery :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does a lot for you behind the scenes.  The equivalent plain DOM code might look something like this:

```
// Get all header elements
var header = document.getElementsByTagName('h1'),
    parent,
    newP,
    text;

// Loop through the elements
for (var i=0, m = header.length; i < m; i++) {
    parent = header[i].parentNode;
    // Check for "section" in the parent's classname
    if (/(?:^|\s)section(?:\s|$)/i.test(parent.className)) {
        newP = document.createElement("p");
        text = document.createTextNode('This paragraph was inserted with JavaScript');
        newP.appendChild(text);
        // Insert the new P element after the header element in its parent node
        parent.insertBefore(newP, header[i].nextSibling);
    }
}
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/LvMep/)

Note that you can also use *textContent/innerText* instead of creating the text node.  It's good that you're trying to learn how to directly manipulate the DOM rather than just letting jQuery do all the work.  It's nice to understand this stuff, just remember that jQuery and other frameworks are there to lighten these loads for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find this function useful (I didn't test)

```
function insertAfter(node, referenceNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(node, referenceNode.nextSibling);

}
```

Comment: You don't need the check for *nextSibling*, if there isn't one it will return *null* - if the second argument to *insertBefore* is *null* then the element is appended to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Oh it's not so bad...

```
var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for (var i=0, l=h1s.length; i<l; i++) {
  var h1 = h1s[i], parent = h1.parentNode;
  if (parent.className.match(/\bsection\b/i)) {
     var p = document.createElement('p');
     p.innerHTML = 'This paragraph was inserted with JavaScript';

     parent.insertBefore(p, h1.nextSibling);
   }
}
```