# remove all tags and styling from object of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting an array of objects from an API:

```
var result = {
  [0]: {
    created_at: "2013-04",
    id: "444556663333",
    num_comments: 1,
    num_likes: 0,
    text: "<p>dfgg</p>",
    title: "title1",
    updated_at: "2013-04"
  },
  user: {
    first_name: "bob",
    id: "43633",
    last_name: "ddd"
  }
}
```

The text field brings in the original formatting from the site. This contains a bunch of different tags such as spans and characters such as, img, p, a, strong, em, br,   &amp How do I strip all of that out of the objects EXCEPT the P tag in the text field BEFORE I pass it into an underscore template?

Thanks!

How can I make this work with my code? not understanding how the selector is working

```
var results = getCanvasPosts(CanvasID, {count: 75, start: ""}); //get posts from API

 $.when(results).done(function(posts){  
    var template = $("#template").html();

//Put function here?

    //merge template and data
    $("#target").html(_.template(template,{posts:posts} ));
 });
```

Comment: I would reccomend the jQuery examples below but this question provides the same result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444891/turn-jquery-into-vanilla-js-insert-p-element-after-h1

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do that in this way:

```
var text = '<p>asdasd</p><div>asddsa</div>';

var only_p = $('p', $('<div>' + text + '</div>'));
```

So you wrap your `text` with `<div>` and select only `p` from it

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var whitelist = "p"; // for more tags use the multiple selector, e.g. "p, img"
$("#text *").not(whitelist).each(function() {
    var content = $(this).contents();
    $(this).replaceWith(content);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEnvr/3/